# PHP Fastcgi won't work if PHP5 mod enabled

Tags: php, apache, module, fastcgi

I just installed multiple PHP versions on my server using FastCGI. Although I can only use them when the module PHP5 is disabled. When the latter is enabled, this configuration of my virtual host seems to be ignored :

```
<Directory /var/www>                
    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.17
</Directory>
```

Everything works fine when PHP5 is disabled but everything is executed using the module PHP5 when it is available. Would you have any idea?

Thank you

Ps: I am obviously on Apache (2.4) on Debian 7

Answer (score 0):

After a moment of reflection, it makes sense that when the PHP module for Apache is available, Apache2 uses it, since it is part of it. My main issue was actually to prevent having to specify a handler for each website I have on the server, and if none is defined, use a default PHP version with FastCGI.

To get this working, I eventually added something like this in my `fastcgi.conf`:

`<Directory /var/www>
    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.17
</Directory>`

With this I was sure to have at least PHP5.5 running for each site, without having to specify the handle in the virtual host. Problem was, what about Phpmyadmin that runs under `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`? Then I removed the `<Directory>` tag and it works.

I don't know if that is the best solution but please let me know if the above is correct or if there would be a better way to perform what I need.

Thank you